Rear Shock Absorbers & Coil Spring Matching
How do you match the correct parts needed for picking shock absorbers and the 'correct' or suitable coil spring for it? Even when using OEM numbers there are slight variations in diameters/length etc.
Also what is the difference between a 'telescopic' and 'spring bearing damper' designs as they are priced almost the same?
